# Constrained-search formulation of DFT: by Levy or by Levy-Lieb

Tags: density-functional-theory

I'm a bit puzzled about how to give the right references for the constrained-search formulation of DFT. Till now, I only heard it being called "Levy constrained-search" but came about some papers and presentations that called it "Levy-Lieb constrained-search". The seminal papers in question are the following:

Levy: M.Levy, *Proc.Natl.Acad.Sci.U.S.A.* **76**, 6062 (1979)

Lieb: [E.Lieb, *Int. Jour. Quant. Chem.* **24**, 243-277 (1983)](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/qua.560240302)

The dates are quite a long way away from each other, but the author of [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/0704.0372) claims that Levy and Lieb developed the constrained search formulation in parallel.
So, I would like to know, what is the relation between the works of these two authors (I unfortunately don't have access to the papers)? Did both of them do the same or did Lieb extend the work of Levy or do both papers contain different formulations entirely? Should I quote both papers and call it "Levy-Lieb" or would the "Levy"-only version be better suited?

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v4): In the future please link to abstract pages rather than pdf files, e.g., http://arxiv.org/abs/0704.0372

Comment: @Qmechanic Thanks for the hint. I will do that in the future. Could you tell me the reason why linking the abstract is preferable?

Comment: Generally for various reasons, such as : (i) not everyone are using a fast internet connection; (ii) permalinks (independent of pdf version number) are preferred.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short (of the top of my head):

- Levy proposed the constrained search formulation of the universal functional. He showed that one could consider all N-representable densities in such a search, instead of searching in the smaller (and nearly impossible to define) space of v-representable densities. It also resolves the issues with degenerate wavefunctions found in the Hohenberg-Kohn formulation of DFT.
- Lieb showed that the ground state can always be found by applying the variational principle to Levy's formulation of DFT. His work also discusses more mathematical aspects.

Consult the book "The Fundamentals of Density Functional Theory" by Helmut Eschrig for more details. (The PDF can be downloaded for free from his website: http://www.ifw-dresden.de/institute/itf/members/helmut-eschrig/)

Comment: Lieb showed that constrained search using <i>density operators</i>, instead of pure states as Levy did, produces a universal functional which is lower semicontinuous and convex.